# Недоперевод в истории правок про конкурс

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, конкурс

Обнаружил в [списке ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/476055/revisions) вот что:

> [image: Ошибочка вышла]

Всплывающая подсказка также не переведена:

> [image: подсказка]

Comment: В Transifex есть только строка ["with $answerLink$ chosen"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265096?key=8e19836534bee31afed57ff8df0e294f), два года назад переведённая как «с выбранным $answerLink$».

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3203/176217)

Comment: @NickVolynkin аналогичная ситуация для [подсказки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265097?key=90275d5741fa42a795916a56015034ee).

Comment: @alexolut сейчас переведено, но текст не согласован. Я так понимаю, этот тред можно в [meta-tag:статус-завершено], т.к. проблема в другой плоскости?

Comment: @Suvitruf общая проблема описана у меня в ответе на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314514/339911

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кривой перевод в истории правок про конкурс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8424/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81)