# Кривой перевод в истории правок про конкурс

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

Недавно нашёл свой старый вопрос [Недоперевод в истории правок про конкурс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4479/) и решил посмотреть, что с этим в итоге решили. Зайдя по старой ссылке, нашёл вот это:

> [image: "Конкурс завершен с выбранным Pavel Mayorov ответил участником val"]

По-моему, это немного расходится с правилами русского языка. Предлагаю заменить на хотя бы

> Конкурс завершён выбором ответа username участником username2

Хотя фраза вряд ли имеет красивый эквивалент в русском языке с таким же построением предложения.

Подсказка является спорной, по-моему должна быть скорее

> ответ, получивший награду

или что-то похожее, хотя не уверен.

P.S.: ещё есть там же

> [image: "Конкурс начат стоимостью 50 баллов репутации участником val"]

но это тема для отдельного вопроса, наверное.

**UPD**

> Конкурс завершён с выбранным ответ участника Pavel Mayorov участником val

За что?!

Comment: @älёxölüt Есть такое, хотя я разобрал вопрос полнее (+подсказка, возможное решение и заметка в P.S.)

Comment: Отменил свой голос и попросил модератора закрыть в нужную сторону :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конкурс завершен с выбранным %username% ответил участником](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8202/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-username-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @Suvitruf уже ответил выше в комментариях (было то же самое)

Answer (score 2):

Поправил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5505) по рекомендации из вопроса:

> выбором $answerLink$

и часть со [ссылкой на ответ](https://ru.traducir.win/string/959):

> ответа участника $username$

Пришлось применить родительский падеж к переводу. Авось в других неподходящих контекстах использоваться не будет.

[Текст всплывающей подсказки](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5609), имхо, достаточно точен.

---

Результат [выглядит так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/476055/revisions):

> [image: победивший ответ]